# How to login in auth0 via Postman

Tags: postman, auth0

I'm playing with auth0 and currently trying to figure out how to log in with Postman

So far I took the following steps:

1. Created an App and set an allowed callback url to `https://google.com`
2. Created a GET request in Postman that looks something like this:

   ```
   https://myauth0.url/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=my_clientId&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com
   ```

When I send the request I get the following response

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sign In with Auth0</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.auth0.com/styleguide/components/2.0.2/media/logos/img/favicon.png">
    </head>
    <body>
...
```

So, It's a default auth0 login window, but how can I procceed and enter username & password to get token?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I've figured out that it's impossible due to the passive authentication:
https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?http#database-ad-ldap-active-

> The main difference between passive and active authentication is that
>   the former happens in the browser through the Auth0 Login Page and the
>   latter can be invoked from anywhere (a script, server to server, and
>   so forth).